# Why are table valued parameters to SQL Server stored procedures required to be input READONLY?

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone explain the design decision behind preventing table valued parameters from being specified as output parameters to stored procedures?

I can't count the number of times I've started building out a data model hoping to completely lock down my tables to external access (you know...implementation details), grant applications access to the database through stored procedures only (you know... the data interface) and communicate back and forth with TVPs only to have SSMS call me naughty for having the audacity to think that I can use a user-defined table type as the transfer object between my data service and my application.

So someone please provide me a good reason why TVPs were designed to be readonly input parameters.

Comment: The odds of there being someone on SO who was present during the design meeting(s) where table-valued parameters were discussed prior to implementation are practically nil. I could post an answer full of *guesses* at some of the potential problems, but it would be just that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but it still worth asking, and honestly your answer does not add up anything here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the presentation on [Optimizing Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Applications Using Table Valued Parameters, XML, and MERGE](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/TechEd/Europe/2009/DAT406) by Michael Rys he says. (at 32:52)

> Note that in SQL Server 2008 table valued parameters are read only.
>   But as you notice we actually require you to write READONLY. So that
>   actually then means that at some point in the future maybe if you say
>   please, please please often enough we might be able to actually make
>   them writable as well at some point. But at the moment they are read
>   only.

Here is the connect item you should use to add your "please". [Relax restriction that table parameters must be readonly when SPs call each other.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299296/relax-restriction-that-table-parameters-must-be-readonly-when-sps-call-each-other)

Srini Acharya made a comment on the connect item.

> Allowing table valued parameters to be read/write involves quite a bit
>   of work on the SQL Engine side as well as client protocols. Due to
>   time/resource constraints as well as other priorirites, we will not be
>   able to take up this work as part of SQL Server 2008 release. However,
>   we have investigated this issue and have this firmly in our radar to
>   address as part of the next release of SQL Server.

Comment: So..."on our radar to address as part of the next release of SQL Server" as of the MSSQL08 release.  ...MSSQL08R2, MSSQL12, now MSSQL14. I wonder what the flipping hold up is.

Comment: @k.alanbates yea, good point about there being three releases and nothing has happened. Not sure you actually need it in your case. How about just using regular resultset(s) from the procedure?

Comment: ...oh, I have no problem getting results from a stored proc. My point is that it just always feels like a hack when an OUTPUT TVP feels like the right way to transport structured data to and from a Database Service layer (read: Stored Procedures)

Comment: K.alanbates have you considered using a table valued function instead? There are some limitations.where dynamic sql is one of them but you have a typed resultset as the return value. Of course you are also limited to one resultset per function. I do however agree that TVP's looks like a half baked feature that they decided will take too much effort to finish.

Comment: dynamic sql is the spawn of Satan.

Comment: I want to take a moment to respond to your last comment.  The purpose of allowing OUTPUT TVPs to be supplied to SPs would be to facilitate a message oriented architecture between data tiers and SQL Server.  A TVF can return a table, but it cannot return its result in a structured format; its result is ad hoc.  As you point out, you also have to execute a dynamic select from a calling client, which is itself a problem, even if the query is generated by some tool like DataSet2.0 -I mean- ....EntityFramework.

Answer (score 6):

Table-valued parameters have the following restrictions(source MSDN):

- SQL Server does not maintain statistics on columns of table-valued
  parameters.
- Table-valued parameters must be passed as input READONLY
  parameters to Transact-SQL routines. You cannot perform DML
  operations such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT on a table-valued
  parameter in the body of a routine.
- You cannot use a table-valued    parameter as target of a SELECT INTO
  or INSERT EXEC statement. A    table-valued parameter can be in the
  FROM clause of SELECT INTO or in    the INSERT EXEC string or stored
  procedure.

there are few options to over come this restriction one is

```
CREATE TYPE RTableType AS TABLE(id INT, NAME VARCHAR )

go

CREATE PROCEDURE Rproc @Rtable RTABLETYPE READONLY,
                       @id     INT
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM   @Rtable
      WHERE  ID = @id
  END

go

DECLARE @Rtable RTABLETYPE
DECLARE @Otable RTABLETYPE

INSERT INTO @Rtable
VALUES      (1,'a'),
            (2,'b')

INSERT @Otable
EXEC Rproc
  @Rtable,
  2

SELECT *
FROM   @Otable
```

through this you can get the table values out

Comment: (Revisiting the post) Your response is appreciated, but it does not address the issue at hand at all.  Your procedure *just happens* to return a result set that *just happens* to match a UDTT because you have written so in an ad hoc script.   The original question was not intended to focus on "how do you get table data out of a stored procedure?"  It is "Why the hell won't Microsoft update SQL Server with OUTPUT TVPs to allow for Message Oriented database communications when they said they'd do it almost 7yrs ago? What the flip is the hold up?"

Answer (score 2):

With respect to (emphasis added):

> So someone please provide me a good reason **why** TVPs were designed to be readonly input parameters.

I just posted a more detailed answer to this on DBA.StackExchange here:

[READONLY parameters and TVP restrictions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120756/readonly-parameters-and-tvp-restrictions/120775#120775)

But the summary of it goes like this:

According to this blog post ( [TSQL Basics II - Parameter Passing Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/06/09/624531.aspx) ), a design goal of Stored Procedure OUTPUT parameters is that they merely mimic "by reference" behavior *when the Stored Procedure completes successfully*! But when there is an error that causes the Stored Procedure to abort, then any changes made to any OUTPUT parameters would *not* be reflected in the current value of those variables upon control returning to the calling process.

But when TVPs were introduced, they implemented them as truly passing by reference since continuing the "by value" model -- in which a copy of it is made to ensure that changes are lost if the Stored Procedure does not complete successfully -- would not be efficient / scalable, especially if a lot of data is being passed in through TVP.

So there is only one instance of the Table Variable that is the TVP, and any changes made to it within any Stored Procedure (if they were not restricted to being `READONLY`) would be immediately persisted and would remain, even if the Stored Procedure encountered an error. This violates the design goal stated at the beginning of this summary. And, there is no option for somehow tying changes made to a TVP to a transaction (even something handled automatically, behind the scenes) since table variables are not bound by transactions.

Hence, marking them as `READONLY` is the only way (at the moment) to maintain the design goal of Stored Procedure parameters such that they do not reflect changes made within the Stored Procedure unless: the parameter is declared as `OUTPUT` *and* the Stored Procedure complete successfully.

Answer (score 1):

### **Be Forewarned.  This code will not work. *That is the problem***

**Note that all code was entered directly into post from memory. I may have a type wrong in the example or some similar error.  It is just to demonstrate the technique that this would facilitate, which won't work with any version of SQL Server released at the time of this writing. So it doesn't really matter if it currently compiles or not.**

---

I know this question is old by now, but perhaps someone coming across my post here might benefit from understanding *why* it's a big deal that TVPs can't be directly manipulated by a stored proc and read as output parameters by the calling client.

"How do you..." questions regarding OUTPUT TVPs have littered SQL Server forums for more than half a decade now.  Nearly every one of them involves someone attempting some supposed workaround that completely misses the point of the question in the first place.

It is entirely non sequitur that you can "get a result set that matches a table type" by creating a Table Typed variable, Inserting into it and then returning a read from it.  ***When you do that, the result set is still not a message.***  It is an ad hoc ResultSet that contains arbitrary columns that "just happen to match" a UDTT.  What is needed is the ability for the following:

```
create database [Test]
create schema [Request]
create schema [Response]
create schema [Resources]
create schema [Services]

create schema [Metadata]

create table [Resources].[Foo] ( [Value] [varchar](max) NOT NULL, [CreatedBy] [varchar](max) NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into [Resources].[Foo] values("Bar", "kalanbates");

create type [Request].[Message] AS TABLE([Value] [varchar](max) NOT NULL)
create type [Response].[Message] AS TABLE([Resource] [varchar](max) NOT NULL, [Creator] [varchar](max) NOT NULL, [LastAccessedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL)

create PROCEDURE [Services].[GetResources]
(@request [Request].[Message] READONLY, @response [response].[Message] OUTPUT) 
AS
insert into @response
     select  [Resource].[Value] [Resource]
            ,[Resource].[CreatedBy] [Creator]
            ,GETDATE()  [LastAccessedOn]
     inner join @request as [Request] on [Resource].[Value] = [Request].[Value]
GO
```

and have an ADO.NET client be able to say:

```
public IEnumerable<Resource> GetResources(IEnumerable<string> request)
{
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=blahdeblah;database=Test;notGoingToFillOutRestOfConnString")
{
   connection.Open();
   using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      command.CommandText = "[Services].[GetResources]"
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      SqlParameter _request;
      _request = command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@request","[request].[Message]");
      _request.Value = CreateRequest(request,_request.TypeName);
      _request.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

      SqlParameter response = new SqlParameter("@response", "[response].[Message]"){Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
      command.Parameters.Add(response);

      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      return Materializer.Create<List<ResourceEntity>>(response).AsEnumerable(); //or something to that effect.  

      //The point is, messages are sent to and received from the database.
      //The "result set" contained within response is not dynamic. It has a structure that can be *reliably* anticipated.
   }
}
}

private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> CreateRequest(IEnumerable<string> values, string typeName)
{
   //Optimally,
   //1)Call database stored procedure that executes a select against the information_schema to retrieve type metadata for "typeName", or something similar
   //2)Build out SqlDataRecord from returned MetaData

   //Suboptimally, hard code "[request].[Message]" metadata into a SqlMetaData collection
   //for example purposes.
   SqlMetaData[] metaData = new SqlMetaData[1];
   metaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.Varchar);
   SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
   foreach(string value in values)
   {
      record.SetString(0,value);
      yield return record;
   }

}
```

The point here is that with this structure, the Database defines [Response].[Message],[Request].[Message], and [Services].[GetResource] as its Service Interface.  Calling clients interact with "GetResource" by sending a pre-determined message type and receive their response in a pre-determined message type.  Of course it can be approximated with an XML output parameter, you can somewhat infer a pre-determined message type by instituting tribal requirements that retrieval stored procedures must insert its response into a local [Response].[Message] Table Typed variable and then select directly out of it to return its results.  But none of those techniques are nearly as elegant as a structure where a stored procedure fills a response "envelope" provided by the client with its payload and sends it back.

Answer (score 1):

Still in 2020, SQL version "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8", I am not able to edit the Table value parameter within the Stored Procedure. So I did the work around by moving the data into Temp table and edited it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_APPLY_CHANGESET_MDTST09_MSG_LANG]
    @CHANGESET AS [dbo].[MDTSTYPE09_MSG_LANG] READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT * INTO #TCHANGESET FROM @CHANGESET 

    UPDATE #TCHANGESET SET DTST08_MSG_K = 0 WHERE ....
     ...............
```